# Adding a class to dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clock that I would like to change the colors of the time on, let's say red for Hours, and green for minutes.

I have my div for the time called `analog`.

```
<div class="analog">analog</div>
```

Then I have my JS that replaces what is in `analog` with my time.

```
//analog time
$('.analog').html(hours + ':' + minutes);
```

I have CSS that changes all of `analog` red, and was planning to add a class to my `minutes` var to change that into green, but can't seem to figure it out.

---

Things that I've tried were variations of `.addClass()` such as:

```
//analog time
$('.analog').html(hours + ':' + minutes).addClass('mins');

//analog time
$('.analog').html(hours + ':').html(minutes).addClass('mins);
```

I'm  not really sure how I can accomplish this since the div is replaced all in one, as the 'analog' becomes '10:27' on screen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you want the hours and mins different colors you will need some other separation inside the div, like two spans each with a class

Comment: You can create 2 spans, one for hour and other for min

Comment: so I would need `$('.analog').html('<span class="hours">' + hours + '</span>' + ':' + '<span class="mins">' + minutes + '</span>');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.analog').html('<span class="hours">' + hours + '</span>' + ':' + '<span class="mins">' + minutes + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tie them together, you can do:

```
$('.analog').html(hours + ':' + minutes);
$('.analog').addClass('mins');
```

Also try creating an `id` for the clock and select it by that (it would be `$('#id')`).

Answer (score 0):

use **span** for hour and other for minute

```
$('.analog').html(
     "<span class='hours'>"+hours+"</span>" + 
     ':' + 
     "<span class='mins'>"+minutes+"</span>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate elements for minutes and hours.

```
$('.analog').html('<span id="hours">' + hours + '</span>' + ':' + '<span id="mins">' + minutes + '</span>');
$('#hours').addClass('hours');
$('#mins').addClass('mins');
```

Or, if you don't need to change those classes dynamically, you can put those classes directly in the span tags.